# Mobilefirst platform analytics v7.1 Analytics Server does not receive Server logs (WASND)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I installed MobileFirst Platform Operational Analytics v7.1 on WASND v8.5.4 and successfully configure it to receive data captures from MobileFirst Server. Although I can receive Data like network response time, device information etc...I can't not receive any Server Logs and client Logs. I have been trying to search on internet from last week but I don't see any solution for this.
Could you please advice me any clue so solve this problem ?

Comment: Inside your MFP runtime configuration inside WAS, have you set the WL analytics url.? Login to WAS > Applications> Application types > Enterprise Applications > IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_XXXXX > Environment entries for Web modules. Set the following "wl.analytics.url" , "wl.analytics.username" , "wl.analytics.password"

Comment: This is strange. Do you have any log capture turned on for your server? Are you doing anything to log client logs?

Comment: @HussamEddin: Yes, I did configure "wl.analytics.url + wl.analytics.username + wl.analytics.password".

Comment: @ChevyHungerford: I noticed that even on MFP console, I don't see any Error logs. This is so strange.

Comment: Do you have wl.analytics.logs.forward in the environment entries set to true? Can you try logging some client logs doing WL.Logger.fatal("Something fatal"); WL.Logger.send(); Those calls are not async so it would be best to set them up in buttons.

Comment: Also, do you have any server logs on the profiles server? Either SystemOut or SystemErr?

Comment: Dear Idan and Chevy Hungerfold, I actually install MFP server and Analytic Server in different WAS environment. In fact, MFP server is in WASND when Analytics server is in WAS standard on another separated machine.

I doubt that Server log and Client Log is not forwarded through network from MFP server to Analytcis server. It requires MFP and Analytics be installed in the same WAS environment in order to get Server log and client log from Analytic console.

Is my hypothesis correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Dear Idan and Chevy Hungerfold,
I actually install MFP server and Analytic Server in different WAS environment. In fact, MFP server is in WASND when Analytics server is in WAS standard on another separated machine.

I doubt that Server log and Client Log is not forwarded through network from MFP server to Analytcis server. It requires MFP and Analytics be installed in the same WAS environment in order to get Server log and client log from Analytic console.

Is my hypothesis correct ?